# Numeric route validation?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel what is correct way to do route parameter validation to ensure the `id` (GET) is numeric?

I am currently doing this way:

```
public function run($id, Request $request)
{
    if (!is_numeric($id)) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message'      => 'ID must be numeric'
        ]);
    }

  // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in your routes themselves, using a [regular expression constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    //
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

The `->where('id', '[0-9]+')` will cause the route to only be valid for numeric values of `id`. Accessing `user/foo` will result in a 404.

Comment: Wow, I never knew I could use `where` for the route.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Yep, you can. Alternatively, you could use route model binding, which'll generate a 404 if a model with the id can't be found. Saves you from having to manually generate an error.

Answer (score 2):

In your route definition you can add a regular expression for the route parameter

```
Route::get('run/{id}', 'YourController@run')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```